# Unique field in Firestore database + Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement a normal authentication system in my app, but I'd like to create a new field for each user that is the "uniqueName" so users can search and add each other in their friends list. I was thinking of adding a textField in the signup form for the uniqueName and updating my User class adding a new String in this way:

```
class User {
  String email;
  String name;
  String uniqueName;
  String userID;
  String profilePictureURL;
  String appIdentifier;

  ...
}
```

Now, since I have this method for the email&password signup:

```
static firebaseSignUpWithEmailAndPassword(String emailAddress,String password,File? image,String name,) async {
try {
  auth.UserCredential result = await auth.FirebaseAuth.instance
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailAddress, password: password);
  String profilePicUrl = '';
  if (image != null) {
    await updateProgress('Uploading image, Please wait...');
    profilePicUrl =
        await uploadUserImageToFireStorage(image, result.user?.uid ?? '');
  }
  User user = User(
      email: emailAddress,
      name: name,
      userID: result.user?.uid ?? '',
      profilePictureURL: profilePicUrl);
  String? errorMessage = await firebaseCreateNewUser(user);
  if (errorMessage == null) {
    return user;
  } else {
    return 'Couldn\'t sign up for firebase, Please try again.';
  }
}
```

how do I have to modify it in order to add this new field in the registration? Since I have to check that the uniqueName insert by the user is effectively unique before creating a new user in the database, what can I do?

Furthermore, I think that it would be cool if this check is made concurrently to the filling of the form, how can I do it? (this is not necessary)

Thanks everyone for the answers

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to save your users in a collection, then check if uniqueName already exists in the collection. If it exists, return error.

Then when a new user account is created, save the uniqueName.

```
// this function checks if uniqueName already exists
Future<bool> isDuplicateUniqueName(String uniqueName) async {
  QuerySnapshot query = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('PATH_TO_USERS_COLLECTION')
      .where('uniqueName', isEqualTo: uniqueName)
      .get();
  return query.docs.isNotEmpty;
}

// call the above function inside here.
static firebaseSignUpWithEmailAndPassword(String emailAddress, String password, File? image, String name,) async {
  if (await isDuplicateUniqueName(name)) {
    // UniqueName is duplicate
    // return 'Unique name already exists';
  }
  // ... the rest of your code. Go ahead and create an account.
  // remember to save the uniqueName to users collection.
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing the following steps:

1. Create your own users collection (for example `users`) in Firestore, which you might have done already. (I don't think that `User` is a good class name, since Firebase Authentication is using the same name. Try `MyUser` or something.)
2. Add [authentication triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) that will ensure that whenever a Firebase user is added or deleted, it will also be added to or deleted from `users` collection, use Firebase `uid` as identifier.
3. Create a solution to check whether a `uniqueName` already exists in `users` collection. You can use a Firestore query, but in this case you have to allow unauthenticated access to read `users`, at least `uniqueName` field. (Since the user is not authenticated yet at this point.) A Firebase Cloud Function is another option.
4. When users enter their desired `uniqueName`, run the check before creating Firebase user. You can do it when user enters this or when you start the signup process.
5. If `uniqueName` is unique, you can try to create Firebase user. Be aware, this step can also fail (for example e-mail name taken etc.). Your `users` document will be created by the authentication trigger you set up in step 2.
6. Finally, you have to store this `uniqueName` in `users` collection. At this point you will have `uid` of the newly created Firebase user, so you can use Firestore `set` command with `merge` option set to `true`, so you don't overwrite other data.

It is important to note that you can't guarantee that the Firebase trigger already created the new document in `users` by the time you arrive to point 6, it is very likely that the trigger is still working or not even started yet. That's why you have to use `set` both in the authentication trigger and in your own code that sets `uniqueName`: which "arrives" first, will create the document, and the second will update it.

Also, for the same reason, you have to allow inserts and updates into `users` collection with Firestore rules. This might sound a little scary, but keep in mind that this is only your own user list to keep track of `uniqueName`, and authentication is based not on this, but on Firebase Authentication's user management which is well protected.

Last comment: this is not a 100% solution. It is quite unlikely, but theoretically can happen, that some else reserves a `uniqueName` between you check whether it's unique and the user is actually created. To mitigate this, it is a good idead to make the check just before Firebase user is created. Even in this case a slight chance remains for duplicates.

Comment: Thank you, I really needed this complete explanation. You and the other guy completely fullfilled my request

Comment: You are welcome, I just spent some time with problems like yours recently.